# Why is this if condition not working fine?

Tags: php

`$isPass` should be "Go to hell", which should differ from 0, yet, the code proves otherwise. Why?

```
<?php 


$marks = 35;
$passing_marks = 36;

$isPass = ($marks > $passing_marks) ? true : "Go to hell";

 echo $isPass;        // prints "Go to hell".
if($isPass == 0){
    echo "Pass";  // prints "Pass", but why and how
} 

?>
```

Comment: Please Read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It would make a lot more sense if isPass was always a Boolean - i.e. it could become true or false ( not true or string). Don't mix data types (and then compound it by trying to compare them to a 3rd data type!)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php And the behavior changed in PHP 8, btw. – https://3v4l.org/CTH1L

Comment: For me this does not print "Pass"

Comment: @LajosArpad if you're running PHP 8 it won't. If you're running <8 it will. Behaviour is different due to changes to how type comparisons work. See CBroe's docs link and multi-version demo, above.

Answer (score 2):

Just try this.

```
<?php
$marks = 35;
$passing_marks = 36;

if($marks > $passing_marks){
echo "Pass";
}

else {
echo "Go to hell";
}
?>
```

You don't need the other variable, just execute the check on one if-statement.